# Why does integer overflow cause errors with C++ iostreams?

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

Ok, so I have some problems with C++ iostreams that feels very odd, but it is probably defined behaviour, considering this happens with both MSVC++ and G++.

Say I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a;
   cin >> a;
   cout << a << endl;
   cin >> a;
   cout << a << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

If I intentionally overflow by giving the first cin a value that is larger than the max limit of an int, all further calls to `cin.operator>>()` will immediately return for some reason, and `a` is set to some value. The value seems to be undefined.

Why, and where is this behavior documented? Is there a way to figure out if such an overflow occured?

Also, this similar program seems to work as I intend. If I overflow the value, it will give `a` some value, and continue on as if the overflow never happened.

```
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a;
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("%d\n", a);
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("%d\n", a);
   scanf("%d", &a);
   printf("%d\n", a);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iostreams is designed to detect errors and enter an error state. You get the same result from integer overflow as from entering a non-numeric string.

Cast `cin` (or any stream) to `bool` or check `cin.rdstate()` to determine if an error has occurred.

Call `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` to flush out the error. It will pick up at the point of the characters that failed.

As for the official documentation, the Standard unfortunately gets a bit inscrutable in the bowels of iostreams. See §27.6.1.2.1, 27.6.1.2.2, and 22.2.2.1.1/11 (no kidding):

> — The sequence of chars accumulated in stage 2 would have caused scanf to report an input failure. ios_base::failbit is assigned to err.

The [documentation for scanf](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fscanf.html) is just as impenetrable, and I'll take it on faith that overflow is supposed to be an error.

Comment: Well, integer overflow in `scanf` actually leads to UB, not to a failure report.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that cin is setting itself to an error state due to the invalid read.

1st reply here explains it.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/93200-cin-checking-and-resetting-error-state/

Just tried this code and it does seem to be setting to fail state

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    int a; 
    cin >> a; 
    if(!cin)
    {
        cin.clear();
    }
    cout << a << endl; 
    cin >> a; 
    if(!cin)
    {
        cin.clear();
    }
    cout << a << endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` starts out with an undefined value. It's not `cin`'s fault. Try:

```
if (cin >> a) {
  cout << a endl;
}
```

It will check whether the read into `a` succeeded before using `a`