# Code unexpectadly giving an infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops

Recently started learning C++ and i wrote a simple program that defines is the given number prime or not, and when the input is zero, it finishes. But i accidentally noticed that it creates an infinite loop when the input is somewhere between 2100000000 and 2200000000. I don't know why this happens, can you please explain to me?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number, i, k;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        cin >> number;
        if (number == 0)
            break;
        for (i = 2; i < round(sqrt(number)) + 1; i++)
            if (number % i == 0)
                k++;
        if ((number == 1) || (k > 0))
            cout << "This number is not prime\n";
        else
            cout << "This number is prime\n";
        k = 0;
        i = 0;
    } while (!(number == 0));
}
```

Comment: A signed int can hold values up to 2\*\*31-1, at which point it underflows to -2\*\*31.

Comment: This happens because you are using a variable of type int, which is signed by default. This means that the list of possible values for that number is between 2^0 and 2^31, since 1 bit is used for the sign. 

Any number that is beyond 2,147,483,647 will cause the range to go back to 0 and hence you will be in an endless loop.

Comment: @RahulKadukar No, signed int doesn't have wrap around on overflow, it's just UB.

Comment: Lots of assumptions about implementation defined behaviour here.

Comment: What's your platform (Windows/whatever) and C++ version (e.g. C++03)? These details might be significant (not sure). Anyway, [this question with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35898958/509868) may be relevant.

Comment: @anatolyg i'm using windows 10 pro and about c++ version... i don't exactly know what it is, but i downloaded visual studio a few days ago so it might be the latest version

Comment: *Debugging tips:* You have two loops in your code. Which one has decided to never end? Are we looking for a value of `round(sqrt(number)) + 1` that `i` never reaches, or are we looking for something that prevents `number` from being updated to zero? Can you simplify your example to have only one loop, yet still demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value overflows its type (`int`) which maximum value is 2147483647 and it results in Undefined Behaviour. If you need to accept large numbers as input you may have to use a `long long`. Additionally, why check if `number` equals 0 twice?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        long long number;
        bool isPrime = true;
        std::cin >> number;
        if(number == 0)
            break;
        for (int i = 2; i < round(sqrt(number)) + 1; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
             }
        }

        if (isPrime)
             std::cout << "This number is prime\n"; //<== print this is this case
        else
             std::cout << "This number is not prime\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```